# Tracker GPS App - Android

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, android-service, accelerometer

I would create an app with the following features:

The App should be listening to the movement of the accelerometer in the background if the cell move continuously, the app should trigger the GPS system and send every 30 seconds some data to a server such as:

- IMEI
- Date and time
- Latitude
- Longitude
- Speed
- Battery voltage

among others...

I am a beginner, I tried to build it but I did not have success ... Below my code, please help me:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxfW2TCNVyLQNmF1Z1FGeHB0WmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What error(s) do you see? Try these links for reference: [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) and [Android GPS Example](http://androidexample.com/GPS_Basic__-__Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=68&aaid=93). Post example code snippets, or give more details of what is not working.

Comment: Not returning error ... but it's not working the way it should ... is not recovering the GPS, and I would like to send the data to the webservice only when the accelerometer is greater than 1 and 30 in 30 seconds .. .. is to be a tracker car ... so only sends if the car is in motion by the accelerometer (not to deplete the battery with GPS turned on all the time) of 30 in 30 seconds ... As I said I am a beginner, and I'm not sure to do this. You can download my code and see what I can change to happen? I'm using a service in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google Play services for location. Checkout [these](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) guidelines, you can set time to get location, when location is changed so on and so forth depending upon your requirement.